# JSON string parsing error in Python

Tags: python, json, django

I am sending a request to an API and it returns this JSON response

```
'{"Reply":{"Header":{"Method":"mGSSCBetHistory","ErrorCode": "0","MerchantID":"BETSTARtest","MessageID": "H140201152657m6k3f"},"Param":{"TotalRecord":"1","BetDatas":"[{"Column1":""}]","ErrorDesc": ""}}}'
```

when I try to convert it to dictionary whether `ast.literal_eval` or `json.loads` it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 367, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 622, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/provider/KENO/tasks.py", line 127, in run
    ['Reply', 'Param', 'BetDatas'], 'post')
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/core/classes.py", line 217, in check_records
    self.result = response.json()
  File "/Users/deanchristianarmada/Desktop/projects/asian_gaming/radar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 826, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 169 (char 168)
```

The reason for this is because of the value of the BetDatas which has a double quote inside a double quote.. Is there an easy workaround for this? Because the only proper solution that I can think of is to tell the third party that I've been sending request to change their JSON response.

Comment: yeah its invalid json.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression to match the offending value and use `re.sub` to escape the match.

```
import re
import json

data = '{"Reply":{"Header":{"Method":"mGSSCBetHistory","ErrorCode": "0","MerchantID":"BETSTARtest","MessageID": "H140201152657m6k3f"},"Param":{"TotalRecord":"1","BetDatas":"[{"Column1":""}]","ErrorDesc": ""}}}'

def escape(match_obj):
    print(match_obj.group(1))
    return match_obj.group(1).replace('"','\"')
REGEX = '(?<="BetDatas":")(\S+)(?=",)'

data = re.sub(REGEX, escape, data)
print(data)
```

Comment: While this might function as a workaround, the safer solution would be to contact the third party and tell them they are returning invalid JSON.

Since they don't escape special characters in this particular instance, it's likely that they don't do it in general, potentially requiring you to add more hacks in place in the future.

Comment: @sxn agreed. a new request could easily break this hack

Comment: Wow thanks! I agree with you, I should report this to the third party than doing hacks

Answer (score 2):

If you exclude "BetDatas" as you correctly guessed then it parses properly

```
import json
json.loads('{"Reply":{"Header":{"Method":"mGSSCBetHistory","ErrorCode": "0","MerchantID":"BETSTARtest","MessageID": "H140201152657m6k3f"},"Param":{"TotalRecord":"1","ErrorDesc": ""}}}')
```

> {u'Reply': {u'Header': {u'ErrorCode': u'0', u'MessageID': u'H140201152657m6k3f', u'Method': u'mGSSCBetHistory', u'MerchantID': u'BETSTARtest'}, u'Param': {u'ErrorDesc': u'', u'TotalRecord': u'1'}}}

There is no obvious way to handle this, it depends on the API provider rectifying their JSONs.